# Hyperledger Network Archive RuntimeException

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

can someone help me resolved this runtimeexception?

```
composer archive create -t dir -n .

[RuntimeException]
The "-t" option does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the right Composer installed?  Maybe you installed `composer` instead of `composer-cli` ?

You can verify what you have with the command `npm ls -g -depth=0` you should see *composer-cli@0.19.7* amongst other things.

If you have the [wrong Composer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/composer) installed try these commands to fix:

`npm uninstall -g composer`

`npm install -g composer-cli`

Comment: i follow your instruction you are correct that I have install composer but i uninstall it and i install composer-cli, now this comes out                         
 -bash: /usr/bin/composer: No such file or directory